# CS50 recover segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

This is Recover from pset4 CS50. There is no error when I compile it. When I run the code I get segmentation fault. I do not understand what exactly is the mistake. I have looked up solutions related to questions on segmentation fault posted by others but they don't seem to solve my problem.

Can somebody explain whats wrong and how do I solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
}

FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(!inFile)
{
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
    return 1;
}

BYTE buffer[512];
FILE *outFile = NULL;
int imageNum = 0;
char fileName[8];

while (!feof(inFile))
{
     fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile);
     if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[4] & 0xf0) == 0xef0)
     {
         if (imageNum > 0)
         {
            fclose(outFile);
         }
         imageNum++;
         sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", imageNum);
         outFile = fopen(fileName, "w");
     }
    if (outFile != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outFile);
    }
}
fclose(outFile);
fclose(inFile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outFile);`... Did you mean: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outFile);`?    ( Definition of [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) )

Comment: Read and understand this: [**Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Thank you for your help. My while loop condition was partially the problem. It has now been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to problem above by changing these lines of code

```
while (!feof(inFile))
```

to

```
while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inFile))
```

and

```
fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile);
fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outFile);
```

to

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inFile);
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outFile);
```

Also the main issue was in my if condition which I changed from

```
if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[4] & 0xf0) == 0xef0)
```

to

```
 if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
```

and the last change

```
imageNum++;
sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", imageNum);
outFile = fopen(fileName, "w");
```

to

```
sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", imageNum);
outFile = fopen(fileName, "w");
imageNum++;
```

Thank you all for your suggestions and help.

Comment: It is good you were finally able to work out the solution!  The way you can let others know this question is resolved is to mark one of the answers posted as the accepted answer (hollow check mark)  Yours is the most complete answer, so marking it would be appropriate :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the segfault is likely this declaration:

```
char fileName[8];
```

For filenames greater than 999,  `fileName` will overflow.

i.e. for `imagenum >= 1000`

```
sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", imageNum);//produces 8 characters + NULL == 9
```

...will produce `"1000.jpg"` which is a buffer overflow, thus segfault.

Making `fileName` larger is the fix:

```
char filename[20];//or larger as needed.
```

***Also***,
per definitions of [fwrite()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm) and [fread()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm), the following function arguments are misplaced:

```
fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile);
fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), outFile);
               ^        ^
```

Should be:

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inFile);
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outFile);
                     ^         ^
```

Comment: I changed the size of my fileName and also the fread() and frwite() functions according to what you mentioned but I am still getting the segmentation fault

Comment: @ZaraK - More information about exactly where the fault occurring would be helpful.  Have you removed `while (!feof(inFile))` from the code yet.  (see comment under your post.)  Are you running in a debugger?  ([gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ran debug 50 and found that the issue was with my if condition..

Answer (score 0):

`fileName` is defined to have eight elements in `char fileName[8];`, but `sprintf(fileName, "%03i.jpg", imageNum);` writes more than eight characters once `imageNum` exceeds 999.